# Stack overflow error in unit test (Resharper, C#, NUnit). test is aborted

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper, stack-overflow

I try to run my unit tests in project but it aborts cause of stack overflow exception.

seems like there are to many calls but I can't understand what's the problem and how to solve it. May be it's smth about how I setup tests

here is my setup and configure code for tests. as you can see I call `_dataQuery.Execute(TestTime)` method and session is aborted after. This method works well in the main project

Hope for your help!

```
      internal abstract class PermissionsTests
      {
           protected static DateTime TestTime;
           protected ILifetimeScope Scope;
           private MyDbContext _dbContext;

           [OneTimeSetUp]
           public void Setup()
           {

            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "PermissionsTests")
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .Options;
            _dbContext = new MyDbContext(options);

            Scope = ConfigureContainer()
                .BeginLifetimeScope(b =>
                    b.RegisterInstance(new FakeUserQuery(_dbContext)).AsImplementedInterfaces());

            if (!_dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()) return;
            TestTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

            //seed data to database
           }
      }
```

```
     internal abstract class DataPermissionsTests : PermissionsTests
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void SetupCustom()
        {
            _dataQuery = Scope.Resolve<IDataQuery>();

            _login = new LoginAsAttribute(userId);
            _login.Login();

            Userdata = _dataQuery.Execute(TestTime);          
             //exception are inside this method. includes some queries
             //needed to get data from database for test user       

            _login.Logout();       
        }
    }
```

UPD

I followed advices and debugged every smallest step in my test and I found method where exception is defenetly (it falls when this query executes):

```
var serviceDocuments = dbContext.ServiceDocumentRelations
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x =>
                    x.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria ||
                    x.Document.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria ||
                    x.Biography.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria ||
                    x.Event.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria ||
                    x.Event.Participants.AsQueryable().Any(p => 
                           p.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria) ||
                    x.Company.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria ||
                    x.News.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria ||
                    x.Media.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria ||
                    x.Note.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria ||
                    x.Assignment.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria ||
                    x.AssignmentPerformer.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria ||
                    x.PhotoUserSettings.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria ||
                    x.BackgroundUserSettings.ServiceInfo.Updated.At >= criteria
                );
```

so I devided this query by conditions and then my problem was solved.
But I don't understand clearly why

THANK YOU

Comment: Usually (though not always), a stack overflow is caused by a hidden recursion (the classic case in C# is a property that refers to itself).  Put a breakpoint where you think the problem is and see if you recurse around and keep coming back to the same place

Comment: Run the test under the debugger. When the StackOverflowException is hit, have a look at the call stack.

Comment: I did but there is no repeated method in call stack if you mean it

Comment: How does the call stack look? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @Klaus Gütter thanks, good advice

Comment: @Lizabeth: Just a note.  It's nice to be thanked, but Stack Overflow etiquette doesn't require it (and in some corners, frowns on "thanks").  If an answer is useful, upvote it (if you get many answers that helped, upvote them all).  If you find another question useful during your research, upvote it (and upvote any answers to that question you found useful).  If one of the answers to your question really helped you out - "Accept" it.  You can also upvote comments to say "thanks".  I realize you didn't get any answers here, but, for the next time...